# Python 3: urllib.request.urlopen and Progressbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, urllib2, urllib

I'm new to Python and have a problem with getting the content of some HTML files / urls and show the status with a progressbar:

This is relevant Code I use:

Progressbar:

```
def createProgressbar(self):
        self.progressbarVar = StringVar()
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar( self.masterWindow, variable=self.progressbarVar, length=400, maximum=100, mode='determinate' )
        self.progressbar.place(x=100, y=760)

        self.progressbarStatus = Label( self.masterWindow, text='Please wait ...', bg='#fafafa', fg='#333', bd=0 )
        self.progressbarStatus.place(x=100, y=730)
```

Read HTML:

```
def readHTML(self):
        # Set new progressbar max, eg. 20 for 20 files to read
        self.progressbar.config(maximum=self.LinkListItemCount)

        # Progressbar Counter
        i=1

        # example for self.LinkListByCatDict
        # self.LinkListByCatDict = {'cat1': ['/test/asd.html', '/test/asd2.html'], 'cat2': ['/test/asd.html', '/test/asd2.html']}

        for item in self.LinkListByCatDict.items():
            actCategory = item[0]

            for linkItem in item[1]:
                url = 'http://www.example.com'+linkItem

                try:
                    req = urllib.request.Request( url )
                    open = urllib.request.urlopen( req )
                    requestContent = open.read()


                    if self.debug == True:
                        print('OK: '+url)
                except:
                    if self.debug == True:
                        print('Error: '+url)


                # Progressbar update
                self.progressbarVar.set(i)

                if self.debug == True:
                    print('Progressbar act: '+str(i))

                i += 1
```

Generally that works fine, but while the loop is processed the whole interface shows only a beachball (Mac OS). At the end of the loop the progressbar jumps from 0 directly to 100%.

Is there a better way to do that, without hanging up the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read the data in one go; that'll block the UI. Instead, read a small amount of data (e.g. 8192/1024 bytes) by passing the amount of bytes to `open.read()`, e.g. `open.read(1024)`. After reading the data, refresh the UI using `app.update()`, assuming app is the Tk instance (somewhere in your code you should have assigned some variable to `Tk()`). Put this in a while loop and stop the while look when the `read()` function returns an empty bytes string (`b""`), signalling the completion of the download. Not sure why the progressbar jumps from 0 to 100%, I'll run the code and investigate.

Comment: This same thing happened to me, but in Java. The best way of not hanging the UI is creating a separate thread to do the work, then periodically send messages to the UI by setting correct data on screen. Make sure to expose the variables you want to modifiy on the UI for easy access from the worker thread!